# Проверка на наличие конкретного слова в адресной строке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток!
У меня на странице есть 4 блока у которых есть свой 'id', по которому я перехожу с другой страницы нажимая на ссылку типа "link#anchor" (то есть обычая якорная ссылка на другую страницу) и таких ссылок 4 как и блоков к ним,
после перехода по ссылке адресная строка имеет типа "..../link#anchor"
и моя задача открывать определенный блок в зависимости от того что прописано в адресной строке допустим ("/link#anchor" "/link#anchor_1" "/link#anchor_2" "/link#anchor_3" "/link#anchor_4") то есть соответственно должен открываться какой то один блок

```
$address = location;

        if ($address.search.indexOf('#win')) {
            $window_1.show('slow');
        };
        if ($address.search.indexOf('#mac')) {
            $window_2.show('slow');
        };
        if ($address.search.indexOf('#android')) {
            $window_3.show('slow');
        };
        if ($address.search.indexOf('#ios')) {
            $window_4.show('slow');
        };
```

Вот примерно так выглядит код, но при нажатии какой либо ссылки открываются все блоки, как решить проблему?

Comment: `indexOf` возвращает `-1` если не найдено, а вы видимо предполагаете что `0`. т.е. вам нужно условие что `indexOf  >= 0`

Answer (score 1):

Если вы будете хранить в хэше id требуемого блока, то тогда достаточно:

```
var hash = location.hash;
$(hash).show('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let $address = location;

let anchors = {
    win: $window_1,
    mac: $window_2,
    android: $window_3,
    ios: $window_4,
};

for(let key in anchors) {
    if (~$address.search.indexOf(`#${key}`)) {
       anchors[key].show('slow');
    }
}
```

Comment: Хорошим тоном ответа было бы добавления комментариев к своим действиям. Возможно, стоит попробовать?